# Handling on rotate on a bottom navigator , navigating on fragments

Tags: java, android

I Am still not getting this part, I am trying to make sure my instance is saved once on rotate for good practice but I have exhausted all my knowledge, everything I rotate I navigate back to main stack which is first fragment. please look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Being a self taught Android developer can be challenging but I appreciate this website.

```
   private final BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
           = item -> {
               List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
               boolean isOnStack = false;
               switch (item.getItemId()) {
                   case R.id.action_transactions:
                       fragment = new TransactionsFragment();
                       for(Fragment frag:fragments){
                           /* Check if fragment is on stack*/
                           if(frag instanceof TransactionsFragment){
                               isOnStack = true;
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                       break;
                   case R.id.action_budget:
                       fragment = new BudgetFragment();
                       for(Fragment frag:fragments){
                           /* Check if fragment is on stack*/
                           if(frag instanceof BudgetFragment){
                               isOnStack = true;
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                       }
                       break;
               }
               /*
                   Prevent duplicate record on back stack and keep consistent back navigation
                */
               if (!isOnStack)
                   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.content, fragment, TAG)
                           .addToBackStack(null)
                           .commit();

               return true;
           };




    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM_POSITION,mPosition);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM_POSITION);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `.findFragmentByTag` for this, first check if the fragment is null. Try adding this code to your onCreate method.

Global

private Fragment fragment;

```
onCreate

fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
if (fragment == null) {
    fragment = new TransactionsFragment();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, so I am betting the idea is to get each Tag.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is that the data is not getting saved, check this code:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM_POSITION,mPosition);

}
```

When saving state, you need to store the data first, before call the super method. When you call the super method, you are saving the data. In your case, you are saving the bundle before put some data.

Replace your code with this (note I just updated your code)

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM_POSITION,mPosition); // put the values
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); // then store the bundle

}
```